# How Can I Programmatically Create A Union Type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a bunch of types that I'm exporting in a file.

```
# myTypes.ts
export type Foo = {
  foo: string
}

export type Bar = {
  bar: string
}

export type Baz = {
  baz: string
}
```

When I import them, I have to manually union them into a new type

```
# otherFile.js
import * as types from './myTypes.ts'
type MyUnion = types.Foo | types.Bar | types.Baz
```

Is there any way that I could do this more programmatically? I'm thinking there should be something like Array#join that does unions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, with TS 2.1+ you can do it writing :

```
type myUnion = typeof types[keyof typeof types];
```

To explain:

- "typeof types" can be seen as the type of the following class :

  ```
  class types {
    Foo: typeof Foo;
    Bar: typeof Bar;
    Baz: typeof Baz;
  }
  ```
- "keyof" return the type of the keys of a type, that is to say :

  ```
  keyof typeof types === 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Baz';
  ```
- The "[]" also known as lookup type operator. A[B] is the type of the type A properties that can be accessed by a key of type B.

  ```
  types['Foo'] === typeof Foo;
  string['length'] === number;
  ```

You can check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html for more information about those two last keywords.

@readers_of_this_answer Let me know if this is clear.